# Как решить, с помощью if или for?

Tags: c

Написать программу, которая по номеру месяца выдает название следующего за ним месяца. (При m = 1 получаем - februari, 4 - may и т.д.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобное отображение проще делать с помощью for, нежели одного if, потому что код получается менее громоздкий при больших размерностях вариантов

```
const char *months[] = {"January", "Feburary", "March"};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(months) / sizeof(months[0]); i++)
    if (n == k)
        printf("Month #%i is %s\n", i, months[i]);
```

а для if

```
if (k == 0)
    printf("Month #1 is January\n");
if (k == 1)
    printf("Month #2 is Feburary\n");
if (k == 2)
    printf("Month #3 is March\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, *February*
Во-вторых,

```
char months[12][20] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
mplusone = months[m];
```

Comment: А вопрос  то про Си.

Comment: Туплю. Тогда только первые два пункта

Comment: А все потому что мне вывелось ЭТО при игнорировании метки с. Но ниче, язык вспомнил маленько

Answer (score 3):

Оформите в виде функции, аргумент строка с названием месяца, результат **int** (-1 нет такого месяца).

Создаете массив строк из 12 элементов (лучше **static**), инициализируете его константами.

При поиске перебираете элементы этого массива в **for(...) { ... }**. Внутри цикла **if** с **strcmp()**. Если нашли, возвращайте текущий индекс. После цикла **return -1** (не нашли).

По поводу синтаксиса, запуска и т.п. см. книжки (учебник). Успехов !

**UPD**
Пардон, облажался, не так прочел условия задачи, просили по **номеру** выдать название,
а я наоборот.

Правильный ответ (для функции):

```
char *
get_month(int n)
{
    static char *m[] = {"jan","feb","mar","apr","may", ... "dec"};

    return (n < 0 || n > 11)? NULL: m[n];
}
```

Не надо ни **for** ни **if**. Впрочем, проверку аргумента можно отнести к if, но смысл в том, что **искать не надо**, надо просто вернуть имя по номеру.

**UPD 2.**  Да, что же такое, сегодня ? Опять не так прочел вопрос. Требуется не месяц по номеру, а месяц следующий за запрошенным номером.

Суть дела не меняется, только надо решить, идет ли за декабрем январь или это ошибка.
Допустим не ошибка. Тогда запрашиваемые номера д.б. 0:11 (как и в приведенном примере), а **m[n]** превращается в **m[(n+1)%12];**

Кажется, все.

Comment: Вроде бы, просто `m[n % 12]`, т.к. массив 0-based, а в условии сказано, что на `1` должно выдавать февраль, т.е. 1 = январь, и номера месяцев 1-based. По всему этому поводу вспомнился славный месяц нулябрь :)

Comment: Точно. Тогда значит, автор считает месяцы с 1 по 12. Ну, в первой строке функции напишем **n--;** и все будет ОК.

Comment: А если пользователь введёт 12? Это нормальный существующий месяц декабрь, следующий за ним - январь. Надо проверку исправить на n>12 и добавить в конец массива названий месяцев "jan".

Answer (score 3):

Обязательно if или for? А если switch? Например:

```
int iMonth;
scanf("%d", iMonth);
char* chMonth=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
switch(iMonth){
case 0:
   chMonth="January";
   break;
case 1:
   chMonth="February";
   break;
///////////// И так далее до December////////
default:
   printf("Invalid month number");
   scanf("%d", iMonth);
   continue;}
```

Если только if/for, то цикл for будет плохим тоном программирования, т.к. это лишняя нагрузка системы.